# Google Appls Gam - New to Gam - How to increase number of users

Tags: google-apps

Our School District is new to Google education and it is our understanding that education domamins have unlimited userse?  This does not appear to be the case.  I have been looking through gooogle apps site.  Does anyone have some good links to increasing ed user accounts?  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Previously, there was a mechanism for requesting more via the Admin console directly. This has been deprecated in favor of a new, higher starting limit. More information can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1625803).

If you need more than 10k accounts, you'll need to contact Enterprise Support. File a case with them via the 'Support' section of the Admin console to get the limit increased.